# yarn-expo-workspaces with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, monorepo

I feel like I was finally able to setup my expo monorepo using expo-yarn-workspaces until I encountered the following error:

**Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. ([https:fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call](http://https:fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call))**

Has anyone successfully created an expo monorepo working with react hooks?

I should also mention that the expo app was working perfectly with no-hoist until I needed to include other packages from the monorepo into it. So it seems the issue is now how yarn-expo-workspaces is not compatible with hooks, or am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly need a little nore explanation re the structure of the repo: I'm using yarn workspaces with an expo app (with yarn-expo-workspaces) and after a few teething problems, it works fine -- I can probably help debug but atm this sounds like you're literally doing what the error message says: calling a hook outside a component, which is not to do with workspaces

Comment: also I have the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920012/monorepo-expo-with-yarn-workspace-and-using-expo-install) of using `expo install` to install react-navigation in a brand new expo app. after a week of headache to config monorepo I really agree with you, there is no enough material to learn the usage.