# monorepo: expo with yarn workspace and using expo install

Tags: expo

I'm trying to setup a React and Expo monorepo project, everything seems good until I want to install `react-navigation` with `expo install` according to the react-navigation docs, because expo install use yarn in the background and because it's a workspace environment this error pop out, which I have no idea how to bypass. any ideas?

```
yarn add v1.21.1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you 
want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).     
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Answer (score 15):

This is how i got it to work with **expo-yarn-workspaces**. 
In my global **package.json** file i added the following codes.

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
}
```

then i created a folder in my root directory called **packages**. 
In my terminal i ***cd packages*** then i created a new expo project with this command

```
expo init app
```

Define the `name` and `version` properties in `package.json`.

then i installed all my dependencies:

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn
```

now its time to install **expo-yarn-workspaces** with

```
npm install --save-dev expo-yarn-workspaces
```

or

```
yarn add expo-yarn-workspaces -D
```

After that you add this script in your **package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
    ...,
    "postinstall": "expo-yarn-workspaces postinstall"
  },
```

create a file and name it **metro.config.js**
and paste the following code

```
const { createMetroConfiguration } = require("expo-yarn-workspaces");

module.exports = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname);
```

in your **package.json** replace/add this line of code

```
"main": "__generated__/AppEntry.js",
```

Run:

```
npm run postinstall
```

or

```
yarn postinstall
```

then you can start your app with the following command to clear the cache:

```
npm start --clear
```

or

```
yarn start --clear
```

> NOTE: If you're running create-react-app and react-native they most be of the same version so you have to run **npm install react react-dom** in both folders to be able to use the same version.

---

> My [github](https://github.com/DNature/expo-yarn-workspace-demo) repo

Useful links:

Article https://divinehycenth.com/blog/yarn-workspace-monorepo.

Github https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-yarn-workspaces

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: This works fine for me, but just curious to know, why are you using npm commands within yarn workspaces? Any challenges with yarn commands?

Comment: I only use npm to create a package.json file because it provides more options than yarn.

Answer (score 0):

The README of the official `expo-yarn-workspaces` package has a good walk through (+ explanations on how things are working):

https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-yarn-workspaces